# Incorrect integer value: '' for column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

What wrong in the following query?
I want to copy some fields from one table to another.

```
INSERT INTO `dle_post_plus` 
(
   `news_id`, `news_read`, `allow_rate`, `rating`, 
   `vote_num`, `votes`, `view_edit`, `access`, 
   `editdate`, `editor`, `reason`, `user_id`
) 
SELECT `id`, `news_read`, `allow_rate`, `rating`, 
   `vote_num`, `votes`, `view_edit`, `access`, 
   `editdate`, `editor`, `reason`, `user_id` 
FROM `dle_post` 
LEFT JOIN dle_users 
  ON (dle_post.autor=dle_users.name)
```

erro:

```
#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'editdate' at row 1
```

Comment: Post both table schema,maybe a value overshoots the required range of the column type.Or a string value in an int column.Make sure all columns are the same type in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all columns are the same type in both tables.Check editdate.Probably in dle_post_plus the column is INT and in dle_post is varchar.

Comment: you are absolutely right, one was varchar the other int. thanks.